# Searching Solution to Convert time into daysm hour and Minutes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dataset that contains time values in a single column, and I need to convert them to a specific format that displays the time as `2 days 7 hours 15 minutes`.

I have attached a [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tQQZcYuI-0i80WC5r9bxO3MAsI3-aIlIu_4DNXVqHYI/edit?usp=sharing) file for your reference, and I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this task.

Comment: How `24:15:00.000` is `2 days 7 hr 15 min`? Can you please explain?

Comment: Sure its baded on Total shift hours `8:30` I have divided it with `24:15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do test this out:

```
=let(shift,8.5,
     map(C4:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,
                               let(d,QUOTIENT(Σ,shift),days,if(d>0,d&"d",),
                                   h,Σ-(d*shift),hours,if(rounddown(h)>0," "&rounddown(h)&"h",),
                                   m,convert(--("0."&ifna(regexextract(h&"","\.(\d+)$"),0)),"hr","min"),mins,if(m>0," "&m&"m",),
         trim(days&hours&mins)
         ))))
     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To convert time values into days, hours, and minutes format, you can use the following formula in Google Sheets:

=INT(A2/86400) & " days " & TEXT(TIME(0,0,MOD(A2,86400)), "h"" hours ""m"" minutes""")

Assuming that the time value is in seconds and located in cell A2, this formula will return the time value in the desired format. You can drag the formula down to apply it to other cells in the column.

Here's an explanation of the formula:

INT(A2/86400) calculates the number of days in the time value by dividing it by the number of seconds in a day (86400).
TEXT(TIME(0,0,MOD(A2,86400)), "h"" hours ""m"" minutes""") calculates the remaining hours and minutes in the time value by using the MOD function to get the remainder after dividing by the number of seconds in a day. The TIME function then converts this remainder to a time value that can be formatted using the TEXT function to display the hours and minutes in the desired format. The use of double quotes within the formula ensures that the text is displayed correctly with the quotation marks.